# Is there any Version Control System in salesforce

Tags: controls, version, system

Can multiple developer work on same org on same class in salesforce. Is there any Version Control  System in Salesforce .Suppose if  a developer A updates the class , how do we mange old code of that class

Comment: Please consider adding more informations. There are always ways to do version control. Salseforce is for cloud computing so you could possibly set up any verrsion control there and use it for your own purpose. Or ask them directly.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly on their platform but there is.

[Salesforce CLI Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference.htm)

I use a Github repository and work out of there. Whenever I am ready to push it to my org I pull from the master and deploy via the metadata api.

That being said, I never used this functionality in Eclipse and have been working with Visual Studio Code for a while. There is a lot of functionality though and allows you to use a VCS in whatever way you’re used to using it. You just have the additional step of having to deploy with a different process. Here’s a reference to all the commands too, it’s helped me out a lot.

[SFDX Command Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force.htm)

and the instructions for installation

[SFDX CLI Installation](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli)

Hope this helps!